# Matplotlibs' affine transform rotation returns a blank cell in a grid figure unless it is the last cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, affinetransform

I need to rotate a plot visualising a mathematical equation involving a transposed matrix. From my reading I have come to understand that this necessitates creating the plot with x and y data in typical order and include an affine transformation to rotate. This has worked in figures where the last cell (using subplot and subplot2grid) is the one requiring rotation. However for one equation the transposed matrix is the middle cell and when I attempt this the image returns a blank middle cell. Is this a bug or have I missed something in my code?

If the data for the middle cell is plotted and rotated in the last cell it is fine

If the middle cell is plotted without the transform it displays fine

If the middle cell is plotted rotated it is blank

Here's dummy code, including the full import list for the parent code in case there are any known interactions. In case it is relevant I am performing this in Jupyter.

```
import pypandoc
import numpy as np
import nipals
import scipy.io as sio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import os
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
from matplotlib import transforms
import pdb

figEx, axEx = plt.subplots(1,6, figsize=(8,8))
axEx[0] = plt.subplot2grid((5, 20), (0, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=5)
axEx[1] = plt.subplot2grid((5, 20), (0, 2), colspan=1, rowspan=5)
axEx[2] = plt.subplot2grid((5, 20), (0, 3), colspan=8, rowspan=1)
axEx[3] = plt.subplot2grid((5, 20), (1, 3), colspan=8, rowspan=2)
axEx[4] = plt.subplot2grid((5, 20), (0, 12), colspan=1, rowspan=5)
axEx[5] = plt.subplot2grid((5, 20), (0, 13), colspan=9, rowspan=5)

p1 = np.random.rand(5,15)
p2 = np.random.rand(801,10)
p3 = np.random.rand(801,15)

axEx[0].plot(p1,'.')
axEx[3].plot(p2,transform=transforms.Affine2D().rotate(np.deg2rad(90))+plt.gca().transData)
axEx[5].plot(p3)

axEx[0].annotate('$P1$', xy=(0.1,0.9),xytext=(0.5, 0.95),
                   textcoords='axes fraction',fontsize = 12,horizontalalignment='center')
axEx[1].annotate('=', xy=(0.5,0.5),xytext=(0.5, 0.5),
                   textcoords='axes fraction',fontsize = 18,horizontalalignment='center')
axEx[2].annotate(r'$P{^\top}$', xy=(0.1,0.9),xytext=(0.5, 0.95),
                   textcoords='axes fraction',fontsize = 12,horizontalalignment='center')
axEx[4].annotate(r'$\cdot$', xy=(0.5,0.5),xytext=(0.5, 0.5),
                   textcoords='axes fraction',fontsize = 38,horizontalalignment='center')
axEx[5].annotate('$P_{-\mu}$', xy=(0.1,0.9),xytext=(0.5, 0.95),
                   textcoords='axes fraction',fontsize = 12,horizontalalignment='center')
for iax in range(6):
    axEx[iax].axis('off')
figEx.savefig('img\middle figure rotated.png',dpi=300)
#    
plt.show()
```

The above code returns a plot with a blank middle cell.
[image: Resulting plot with middle plot rotated]
Swapping the last two data plots:

```
axEx[5].plot(p2,transform=transforms.Affine2D().rotate(np.deg2rad(90))+plt.gca().transData)
axEx[3].plot(p3)
```

returns 3 complete cells with the last cell rotated as expected[image: rotated plot moved to last cell]

Removing the affine transform from the middle cell displays it (and all other cells) as expected, with the middle plot unrotated.[image: middle plot not rotated]

```
axEx[3].plot(p2)
axEx[5].plot(p3)
```

No error messages were returned and the image is able to save as displayed in the browser.

Comment: `plt.gca()` is the last axes in your stack (currently active = last created). Use the axes you want to show the data in instead.

Comment: Fantastic, I'd naively assumed that it would grab the axis the command was being applied to, but in hindsight the axEx[3] is not the current axis at that point. axEx[3].plot(p2,transform=transforms.Affine2D().rotate(np.deg2rad(90))+axEx[3].transData) works exactly like I hoped.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest if you want to just pop an quick answer then I can select as answered so as to avoid this being an unanswered question.